# User can't change their own location after registration anymore

Tags: users, location

i'm using the loaction module for user locations. At the registration form a new user has to enter his oder her location and it will be displayed in his profile. When the user tries to edit his or her location afterwards the fileds will be empty after saving the changes, but the "delete" and "re-geocode" checkboxes show up.

Under permission I gave the user the all the user location permission, so he or she is allowed to edit his oder her own locations as well as administer user locations in general.

I also tried to remove the location field and put it in again - no changes.

Any hints on why this is happening?

Thanks a lot!

[image: loaction form before saving]
[image: location form afer saving]